# How do I extract a number from an HTML span using jQuery?

Tags: jquery

Using jQuery, I would like to extract a number from a `<span>` and use it to calculate a new value.

```
<div class="post-100" data-postid="100">
   <span class="score">3</span>
</div>
```

I've got the general Idea, but I can't figure out how to reference the existing span value:

```
if (response.newvoteid == null)
{
    $(".post-" + $(this).data("postid") + " .score").text(
            parseInt( **EXISTING VALUE + 1 OR -1**));
}
```

**Update:** I am now using the following which fails to calculate the new value, but simply adds a number to the text. For example, `<span class="score">3</span>` becomes `<span class="score">31</span>`

```
var number = $(".post-" + $(this).data("postId") + " .score").text();
$(".post-" + $(this).data("postId") + " .score").text(number + 1);
```

Comment: Why don't you write `$(this).find('.score')`?

Comment: SLaks, good idea. I've found a way to find the score, but now it's appending the new number to the span instead of appending the calculation. See my update if this comment doesn't make sense.

Comment: That's what `parseInt()` is for. Otherwise it thinks you're doing a concatenation. Also, there's a simpler way to update the old value. [See my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4423750/how-do-i-extract-a-number-from-an-html-span-using-jquery/4423818#4423818).

Comment: Why are you using an attribute in a div to get a reference to the div holding the attribute in the first place? Either you have a reference to the div, in which case you can do `var number = $(this).find('.score').text()` or you don't, in which case `$(this).data("postId")` won't work anyway.

Comment: Also, why don't you just store the `score` in a variable, and update the score within the HTML to match it, rather than a read-modify-write approach.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just pass a function to `.text()` that returns the old value incremented (or decremented):

```
$(".post-" + $(this).data("postid") + " .score").text( function( i, txt ) {
    return ( parseInt( txt, 10 ) + 1 ); // Returns the old value,
});                                     //      plus (or minus) 1.
```

Answer (score 8):

parseInt() is a helper method which requires the string to be parsed as an argument like this:

```
parseInt($(".score").text())
```

To do a calculation you can now add your number to the result of parseInt():

```
var newVal = parseInt($(".score").text()) + 1
```

its not clear to me, how you want to select the span.
Can you explain this a bit clearer?

The above code selects the content of the span via its class for example.

Comment: Jan, the span selection is not an issue at all. The issue is getting the calculation. Please see update.

Comment: You have to call parseInt on your text-result. Afterwards you can do the math. I have updated my answer to show the add operation. In your edit you call the +-operator on a string datatype (result of function text()). That will append the value to the string.

Answer (score 0):

```
 <span class="score">3</span>
```

you have a class name already defined, so using class name you can get the text inside it as below

```
$(.score).text();
```

api here

http://api.jquery.com/text/

the above code gets you 3

Answer (score -1):

```
$(spanId).text();
```

would get the value/text within the span tag.

so something like:

```
var number = $(spanId).text();
```

will get you the value, then you can check if its a valid number and parse as you like.

```
var intRegex = /^\d+$/;

var number = $(spanId).text();
if(intRegex.test(number)) {
 ...//proceed cuz it's a number
}
```